# How to avoid if statements with equals when using enum type?

Tags: java

Does exists some way to avoid many if statements when use enum type? Maybe I should use some design patterns  instead use if statements.

I have many cases in my code which looks like this:  // pseudo code

```
public void methodOne() {    
    if(User.Type.SomeType == user.Type && User.Type.SecondType == user.Type)
        doSomething();
}

public void methodTwo() {
    if(!User.Type.OtherType == user.Type && !User.Type.SecondType == user.Type)
        throw new BadTypeException();
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: `if(User.Type.SomeType == user.Type && User.Type.SecondType == user.Type) ` would never match right?  Did you mean `||` ?

Comment: Can you post your actual usecase? If statements can in general be replaced by methods defined in enums, with polymorphic methods, and with design patterns such as "visitor" - but you have to consider the concrete case to know which approach to take

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `EnumSet`:

```
private static final Set<User.Type> SET = EnumSet.of(User.Type.SomeType, User.Type.SecondType);

if (SET.contains(user.type)) {
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is looks much better than     if(!User.Type.OtherType == user.Type && !User.Type.SecondType == user.Type). Thanks:)

Comment: That should be `private static final Set<User.Type> SET`.  Note that the *variable* may be final, but the EnumSet itself is still mutable;  use `SET = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(…))` to make it truly immutable.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the correct type.  I've left out the immutable part, it is not really an issue for a `private` (a class should know what to do with its own fields).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like using vararg functions for this case in particular

```
private static boolean matchesAnyState(User.Type type, User.Type... types) {
    for (User.Type listType: types) {
        if (type.equals(listType)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create a utility class and move those checks to static method, but this is not OOP way and won't fix your design.

Instead I will suggest you to think about subclassing you User.
So instead of having `User.Type` you will have `interface User` or `abstract class User` and subtypes:

```
class AdminUser implements User

class GuestUser implements User
```

And so on. 
Method `doSomething` should be moved to your `User` interface and implemented by subclasses.
And you will just ask for your user to `doSomething`.